# Check QGIS processing Saga version from a plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, saga

I am writing a QGIS plugin using SAGA by Processing. Is is possible to test whether SAGA is installed and which version is on?

For GDAL, it's OK with:

```
processing.tools.raster.gdal.__version__
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might to want to look at some of the [python code for SAGA algorithm providers](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga), especially the module **SagaUtils.py** - that has a `getSagaInstalledVersion()` function, and a few functions for building the paths etc.

This is an example from the Python Console:-

```
>>> processing.algs.saga.SagaUtils.getSagaInstalledVersion()
'2.2.0'
```

Looking at the code, it's a wrapper around an external call to `saga_cmd -v` with retry logic

Comment: This is concise and works right !